# how to change the class attribute of a selected item in the navigation bar

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap with grails and have the following in my layout:

```
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="${createLink(uri: '/request/new')}">My Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

On my page I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="bootstrap">
    </head>

    <body>
        sometext
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question**

In my layout how do I detect when the `My Link` action is clicked? so that I can highlight it using `class="active"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I tend to do this.

First, in your layout, you would do something like this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="${ pageProperty(name:'meta.nav').equals( 'foo' ) ? 'active' : null }"><a href="${createLink(uri: '/request/new')}">My Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And in your page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="bootstrap">
        <meta name="nav" content="foo"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        sometext
    </body>
</html>
```

`foo` is the trigger to apply the `.active` class.

Answer (score 5):

Use actionName and controllerName to know in which action you are.

```
    <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li ${controllerName == 'request' && actionName == 'new' ? 'class="active"' : ''}><a href="${createLink(uri: '/request/new')}">My Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

By the way, I suggest you to use `g:link` instead of `g:createLink` where it is possible. Here :

```
    <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li ${controllerName == 'request' && actionName == 'new' ? 'class="active"' : ''}><g:link controller="request" action="new">My Link</g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout gsp to:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li onclick="javascript: this.setAttribute("class","active");">
            <g:remoteLink controller='request' action='new' update='data'>My Link</g:remoteLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="data">
    <g:layoutBody />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (notice it's slightly different to Isammoc's answer)

```
<li class="${controllerName == 'user' && actionName == 'profile' ? 'active' : ''}"> profile </li>
```

Comment: Could you give some insight into how it is different and why?