# grails current page highlight

Tags: grails, gsp

In grails I have a menu.  I'm trying to highlight the menu item for the active page:

```
link1
link2 (show as bold if the controller action partially matches this gsp name)
link3
```

I have working code but it seems like there would be a better way.

Taglib works fine:

```
def active = { attrs, body ->
    for (page in attrs.check) {
        if (params.action.startsWith(page)) {
            out << "current"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This option works fine, but seems wordy:

```
<li><a href="${createLink(action: 'contactInfo')}" title="Contact Info" class="<xyz:active check='${['contactInfo']}'/>">Contact Info</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(action: 'aboutYouFamily')}" title="About You" class="<xyz:active check='${['aboutYouFamily', 'aboutYouBackground', 'aboutYouCharacteristics', 'aboutYouLifestyle', 'aboutYouApplicant2']}'/>">About You</a></li>
```

This blows up:

```
<g:link action='myProfile' class="${<xyz:active check='${['myControllerAction']}'/>}">My Profile</g:link>
```

I don't believe you can pass a taglib as a parameter to g:link

I also have the requirement that multiple gsps/actions would cause a link to be active because of how they are named:

```
aboutYouLocation
aboutYouBackground
aboutYouEducation
```

all make this link the active one:

```
About You
```

I can do a partial match, but I've also got some actions/gsps that begin with aboutYour (extra R) resulting in my use of the array being passed into my taglib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the class attribute of a selected item in the navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146950/how-to-change-the-class-attribute-of-a-selected-item-in-the-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a standard way of doing that with the [Platform Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core). It will provide you a [Navigation API](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html):

*grails-app/conf/AppNavigation.groovy*

```
navigation = {
    // Declare the "app" scope, used by default in tags
    app {
      contact(action: 'contactInfo')
      about(action: 'aboutYouFamily')
    }
}
```

*grails-app/view/_menu.gsp* (template that you can use in your layout or GSP's)

```
<nav:menu scope="app" id="navigation" />
```

You can also customize the html generated for your menu, check the [custom item rendering](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/ref/Navigation%20Tags/menu.html).

Comment: That is a great plug-in.  I wish I had known about it earlier.  It's cleaned up my code a lot.

Comment: Yeah, a great plugin indeed :-) I think that more grails plugins / applications should use it, make things more standard.